# Disable automatic "zoom on input focus" in mobile browsers

Tags: browser, zooming

Although a software developer, I'm asking this as an end user. Some mobile browsers automatically zoom in when a text input element is focused; I think this happens when the font size is < 16px. Is there some way (as an end user of the site, not a developer of it) to disable this? And if not, why not? If the fonts/inputs are too small and I need to zoom in to see/interact with them, I'd rather do the zooming manually since I usually don't need it.

I understand that this is a valid accessibility feature to make forms easier to use when site developers don't design their sites for mobile, but it shouldn't be forced on all users. As someone who uses reduced motion on all their devices, unexpected zoom/pan/scale/etc effects are extremely annoying.

Fortunately, I have a workaround, but it shouldn't be necessary. I use Kiwi (a Chromium fork) on Android. My workaround is to use a custom TamperMonkey script to fix the offending sites by adding the CSS rule `body { touch-action: none; }`. This prevents the auto-zoom, but also disables **all** pinch zooming- not ideal, but good enough for my use case. I also tried using the `<meta/>` tag techniques [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472891/how-can-i-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page), but they don't seem to be supported anymore. This is especially necessary on a tablet. Although it's technically a mobile device, my tablet screen is as big as a laptop's, and zooming is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I cannot assist but I can observe that what you suggest does not occur on iPhone Edge or Safari IOS 17